# What does class Derived1 : Base {}; mean?

Tags: c++

I know what

```
class Derived1 : public Base {};  

class Derived1 : private Base {};
```

mean, but what does

```
class Derived1 : Base {};
```

mean?

I found an example of this in the excellent boost article on exception handling: http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html under the section "2) virtual inheritance".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the visibility is not specified, private is used. So:

```
class Derived1 : Base {};
```

is the same as

```
class Derived1 : private Base {};
```

Comment: *Related*: The default inheritance for `struct`s is public.